# Jenks Classification with multiple colors PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, jenks

I want to make a Jenks classification in Python for QGIS 3.16 **with 5 classes** and 5 colors for a shapefile layer.

I've tried this code :

```
renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer() 
renderer.setClassAttribute('class') 
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
color1 = QColor (192, 222, 164)
color2 = QColor (215, 25, 28)
layer.renderer().updateClasses(layer, QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Jenks, 5)
layer.renderer().updateColorRamp(QgsGradientColorRamp(color1, color2))
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

But I can not use more than 2 colors for the ColorRamp. (Or I don't know how)

And I want **5 colors**...

I've try an other code with an other classification for show what color I need:

```
renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer() 
renderer.setClassAttribute('class')    
RangeList = []   
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())  
symbol.setColor(QColor("#729b6f"))                           
Range = QgsRendererRange(0, 5, symbol, 'Group 1')                 
RangeList.append(myRange)    
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
symbol.setColor(QColor("#fbdd6d"))
Range = QgsRendererRange(5.1, 10, symbol, 'Group 2')
RangeList.append(myRange)    
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
symbol.setColor(QColor("#e79650"))
Range = QgsRendererRange(10.1, 15, symbol, 'Group 3')
RangeList.append(myRange)    
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
symbol.setColor(QColor("#e36a19"))
Range = QgsRendererRange(15.1, 20, symbol, 'Group 4')
RangeList.append(myRange)    
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
symbol.setColor(QColor("#d7191c"))
Range = QgsRendererRange(20.1, 25, symbol, 'Group 5')
RangeList.append(myRange)
```

I don't know if I need to use math formula in the second classification, or if I need to use other function in the Jenks classification...

Answer (score 2):

The `QgsGradientColorRamp` class takes additional args e.g https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGradientColorRamp.html so the following should do what you want.

```py
# Below line can be commented if not standalone
layer = iface.activeLayer()

gradientColorRamp = QgsGradientColorRamp(QColor("#729b6f"), QColor("#d7191c"), discrete=False, stops=[
    QgsGradientStop(0.25, QColor("#fbdd6d")),
    QgsGradientStop(0.5, QColor("#e79650")),
    QgsGradientStop(0.75, QColor("#e36a19"))
])
layer.renderer().updateColorRamp(gradientColorRamp)

# Update the layer tree panel
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Although I've made a technical answer, from a semiology viewpoint, I'm not sure it's wise to use this particular ramp as it's not a sequential color scheme e.g https://www.axismaps.com/guide/using-colors-on-maps and if you use Jenks, you expect a sequential color scheme whereas your color ramp start from green to go to red and it's not.